# I like/don't like someone to do something

Tags: grammar

Do people say this kind of sentences to others? I don't often see this kind of sentences. I often see sentences like "**I would/wouldn't like someone to do something**", but not "**I like/don't like someone to do something**".

Comment: You're quite right that native speakers avoid using the infinitive after (unmodified) ***like***, but we have no such problem with ***would like***. But this is effectively just "established idiomatic preference" with that particular verb - you can use either the infinitive *or* a "gerund" with, for example ***I don't want him to do it / I don't want him doing it***. Note that the "idiomatic rule" for ***like*** is the same with or without negation, but it can make a difference with ***want*** (***I want him doing it*** is relatively unlikely in most contexts).

Comment: @FumbleFingers  Do you mean "**I don't want him to do it**" is more formal than "**I don't want him doing it**" in most contexts?

Comment: I certainly never said (or at least, never *intended* to say) that. I hadn't even *considered* the possibility that either version might be considered more "formal" than the other, when I wrote that first comment. I suppose we'd have to accept that contractions such as ***wouldn't like / don't want*** are "informal", and undeniably ***negation*** is relevant here (like I said, non-negated ***I want him doing it*** is very unlikely compared to ***I want him to do it***). But to be honest, I suspect "level of formality" is an irrelevant distraction in the current context.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Sorry, but what do you mean by "**I want him doing it** is very unlikely compared to **I want him to do it**"?

Comment: ***unlikely = uncommon***. See [this chart,](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=wanted+him+doing+it%2Cwanted+him+to+do+it&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cwanted%20him%20to%20do%20it%3B%2Cc0) for example.

Answer (score 2):

That construction is OK: "I don't like my students to bother me when I am trying to write."; "I don't like the children to use the oven when I'm not home."; "I don't like my gas tank to get below a quarter full." Also, "I like my dentist to use Novocaine."; "I like a man to be sensitive and caring." Where I come from (Ca, USA), all of those sentences sound natural and correct.

All four of the constructions you mention "I like/don't like [someone or something] to [verb]" *and* "I would/wouldn't like [S/O or S/T ] to [V]" are acceptable, idiomatic, and sound fine. They usually do have slightly different meanings though. "I like" or "I don't like" is for real situations; "I would like" or "I wouldn't like" is for hypothetical, future, or somehow non-real occurrences.

Consider the pair: "I don't like a visitor to come to my home without phoning first." vs. "I wouldn't like a visitor to come to my home without phoning first." The first sentence is about what a visitor does that the speaker doesn't like. But the second sentence implies a situation that is hypothetical. The speaker doesn't say he *doesn't like* it, but only that he *wouldn't like* it (if it were to happen). The first sentence implies visitors sometimes do come without phoning. The second sentence implies that they never do.

Similarly, in the positive sense, "I like my dentist to use Novocaine." implies some experience with a dentist who uses Novocaine, and the speaker likes it that way. But "I *would* like my dentist to use Novocaine." implies that the dentist does not use Novocaine, and the patient would like it *if he did*.

Comment: I'm not sure exactly *how* it's relevant, but it seems to me *I don't like you to go swimming **right now*** (or ***...yesterday, in a minute, tomorrow***, etc.) are "non-idiomatic" because they identify a single "point in time" - which by implication forces the interpretation that what I'm saying I don't like is ***a single instance** of a specific action*. Consider *I don't like you to go swimming **on Sunday*** - perfectly valid if we assume ***Sunday*** is just an alternative to plural ***Sundays*** (a *repeated* action), but ***not*** if we suppose it refers to, say, ***next Sunday***.

Comment: ...so to all intents and purposes, ***I don't like you to go swimming on Sunday*** is completely unambiguous (you often go swimming on Sundays, but I don't like that). But  ***I don't want you to go swimming on Sunday*** is far more ambiguous - either it means (almost?) exactly the same as the ***like*** version, OR it means *I don't want you to go swimming **on the specific contextually-relevant Sunday in question.***

Comment: @Lorel C. Can you give me some examples about **"I like someone to do something"**?

Comment: @FumbleFingers So, if I say **I don't want you to go swimming right now** (or **...yesterday, in a minute, tomorrow,** etc.), will that be non-idiomatic too?

Comment: @RelativeClausesvsParticiple: Negated or not, *I [don't] want you to go swimming yesterday* is simply nonsensical. There's nothing unusual about non-negated *I want you to go swimming in a minute*, but you'd need to contrive a context where *I don't want you to go swimming in a minute* would make sense (such as immediately following it with *...I want you to finish your homework first, and **then** you can go swimming*).

Comment: *I don't like you to wear that hat.* is good.  *I don't like you to wear that hat in the movie theater.* is also good.  *I don't like you to wear that hat today* is not good.  The thing must be something that is capable of being repeated, a **practice** of some kind.

Comment: Are there any examples about **"I like someone to do something"** that sound natural and okay?

Comment: @Relative Clauses vs Participle, I think so: "I like my dentist to use Novocaine." "I like a man to be sensitive and caring." "I like the music to play quietly in the background."

Comment: @Lorel C.: Do they mean **"I would like my dentist to use Novocaine." "I would like a man to be sensitive and caring." "I would like the music to play quietly in the background."**?

Comment: But consider: "I like my dentist to try drilling my teeth without Novocaine once, just to see how much it would hurt." "I like my husband to be a little more understanding next time that happens." "I like the music to cease for just fifteen minutes so I can think !" These sentences sound a little *off*. It's the nature of the thing that determines whether "I like it" sounds right or I *would* like it". If it is a real thing that happens, you can say, "I like...", but the 3 unnatural sentences above describe situations that are hypothetical, or in the future, etc.

Comment: Hypothetical, future, or unreal situations, you can't say, "I like." You can only like it conditionally (if it were to happen), so you need to say, "I *would* like." Many sentences could be stated either way, "I like ..." OR "I would like ...", but they mean slightly different things.

Comment: @Relative Clauses vs Participle, "I *would* like my dentist to use Novocaine." implies that in reality, he doesn't. "I like my dentist to use it." means you have experienced your dentist using N., and you like it. Similar with the other sentences. "I *would* like the music quiet, etc." makes it sound like you *would* like it (*if* it were to be that way, but it's currently not).

Answer (score 1):

It sounds fine to say, "I don't like *someone something*," when the speaker has control over *someone doing something*.  The speaker is expressing their own preferences and the implication is that they can make it happen:

- I don't like my students to bother me when I am trying to write.  *The teacher is in charge of the students, and can tell them not to bother her.*
- I don't like my gas tank to get below a quarter full.  *I can fill my gas tank 
  sooner.*

It it sounds strange if the speaker has no control over the situation:

- I don't like my neighbors to play loud music at night.  *I can't control my neighbors, this sounds odd.*
- I don't like the police to arrest an innocent man.

In those cases, what you can do is express how you feel about the event:

- **I don't like it when** my neighbors play loud music at night.
- **I don't like it when** the police arrest an innocent man.

If you use **wouldn't**, it can also sound fine, but the implication is again that the speaker has control over this hypothetical action, even if indirectly:

- I wouldn't like my neighbors to play loud music at night.  *Could be an answer to, "Would you like...?" or contrasting the choice of living situation of the speaker's neighbors to someone else's*
- I wouldn't like the police to arrest an innocent man.  *Something you might say when arguing with yourself about coming forward with evidence.  Or an opinion you might express about the risks of a poorly worded law.*

You can also express how you would feel about the event:

- **I wouldn't like it if** my neighbors played loud music at night.
- **I wouldn't like it if** the police arrested an innocent man.